# Cannot create new columns in database using @column

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I'm working in a task that demands to create a new status to my class and so I need to insert a new column in the database table. 
I tried to use this in my TO file:

```
@Column(name="nameOfNewColumn")
private Boolean nameOfNewColumn;
```

I also included the set and get methods, but it just doesn't work, I open the table with Postgres and it doesn't appear. I reseted the server, reconnected the data base, but nothing happens. I'm using eclipse oxygen and PgAdmin 4.

I believe that it must be a simple problem, but I couldn't find anything on the web (maybe I don't know which words to use xD). I'd appreciate any kind of help! :)

Comment: What are your hibernate schema option, probably you have validate on those

Comment: I'm using hibernate: <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
I did some tests and when I try to create a new database it adds the column I want, but when I try to add a column in an already existing database, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm restoring my DB from an external backup, does it have something to do with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some data is missing - Do you use hibernate/ flyWay/ liquiBase ?

you can **for example** add

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

to adjust the schema automatically

(or the relevant syntax at flyWay (sql) / liquiBase (xml)) .

Comment: Yes! I'm setting <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
My problem is that when I create a new DB, it comes with the new columns I added, but if I restore my DB from a backup and try to update it, I cannot create the new columns.